# Calculate the total penalty received for a particular month

Tags: python

I want to calculate the total penalty received (save data in list) for a particular month but I don't know how to do it. Can anyone please help?

```
bookcode = str(input('Enter Book Code To Return: ')) 
day = int(input('Enter Days Borrowed:'))

if(0 <= day <= 5):
        print('You have returned your book successfully =)') 
else:
    penalty = (day-5) * 1
    print('You have to pay RM%.2f ,%penalty)


print('\nYou have to pay RM','%.2f'%penalty)
```

Comment: Can you give a use case and the output that you expect?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've provided the code but not the use case for it (is it being ran at the end of each month? every time someone wants to return a book? etc).

For the time being let's assume that we're running this code every time someone wants to return a book.

So to break it down:

1. your application needs to be aware of what date we currently have
2. it needs to load previous data that has been submitted from some form of persistent storage - either a database or file.

---

To tackle our date problem we can use the `datetime` [library that's part of pythons standard library](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html).

We import it and call the `datetime.datetime.now()` method which gives us a `datetime` object which contains current date and time.
We can then use said object to figure out what month we're currently in. Like so:

```py
import datetime

now = datetime.datetime.now()
print(now.month)
```

Note that this will return an integer. To get month name we can use the calendar api (also found in the standard library)

```py
import datetime
import calendar

now = datetime.datetime.now()
print(calendar.month_name[now.month])
```

Now that we have a month we can append our data against it in a dictionary.

To keep track of what data has been entered before, we'll need some persistent storage. Easiest way would be to create a file and write data to it in a `json` format.

Start by importing `json` from the standard library (again). Then create a dictionary which we'll write to our file.

```
import os

# our data file name
data_file_name = 'data.json'

# check if there is an existing file
data_present = os.path.isfile(data_file_name)

# if present, open the file in read only mode and fetch it's contents.
if data_present:
    with open(data_file_name, 'r') as _f:
        json_data = _f.read()
else:  # data file not found, create one and a dummy json object.
    json_data = json.dumps({calendar.month_name[i]: [] for i in range(1,13)})
    with open(data_file_name, 'w+') as _f:
        _f.write(json_data)

# try parsing json data
try:
    data = json.loads(json_data)
except ValueError:
    print('Failed to decode json data')
```

---

Now that we have the missing pieces we can add that code to your application.

```py
import datetime
import calendar
import json
import os

now = datetime.datetime.now()  # Get current date and time
month = calendar.month_name[now.month]  # current month

# Read data from the json file.

# our data file name
data_file_name = "data.json"

# check if there is an existing file
data_present = os.path.isfile(data_file_name)

# if present, open the file in read only mode and fetch it's contents.
if data_present:
    with open(data_file_name, "r") as _f:
        json_data = _f.read()
else:  # data file not found, create one and a dummy json object.
    json_data = json.dumps({calendar.month_name[i]: [] for i in range(1, 13)})
    with open(data_file_name, "w+") as _f:
        _f.write(json_data)

# try parsing json data
try:
    data = json.loads(json_data)
except ValueError:
    print("Failed to decode json data")


bookcode = str(input("Enter Book Code To Return: "))
day = int(input("Enter Days Borrowed: "))
penalty = None  # Make sure we have a penalty variable

if 0 <= day <= 5:
    print("You have returned your book successfully =)")
else:
    penalty = (day - 5) * 1
    print(f"RM {penalty:2f} added to {month} penalty")

# Now add the additional data to our data.json file.
if penalty:  # Resolves to true if it's not None or False
    with open(data_file_name, "w") as _f:
        data[month].append(penalty)  # Add penalty to the month in our data.
        _f.write(json.dumps(data))  # Write our new data to file in json format

# Show user overall penalty
overall_month_penalty = sum(data[month])

print(f"\nYou have to pay RM {overall_month_penalty}")
```

Note that this only works on year to year basis. You'll have to delete the `data.json` at the beginning of a new year.

References:

- [json python module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html)
- [json standard](http://www.json.org/)
- python datastructures ([lists](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#more-on-lists), [dictionaries](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#dictionaries))
- [datetime module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html)
- [calendar module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/calendar.html#calendar.month_name)
- [os module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html)
- [python file context manager](https://book.pythontips.com/en/latest/context_managers.html)

PS: You have a typo: `print('You have to pay RM%.2f ,%penalty)` should be `print('You have to pay RM%.2f' %penalty)` (add `'` and remove `,`)